# Recover corrupted java script in visual studio 2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, corruption

I am working on ASP.net project. In evening while leaving the company I close the solution, at that time the code was perfect. But today when I open the solution the javascript was corrupted as in image:

[image: corrupted java script file]

I searched on google in lots of links. But I find solution in http://www.samnoble.co.uk/2014/11/30/visual-studio-crashes-and-a-corrupted-cs-file/ but I cant recover from this steps.

Anybody has idea regarding this?

Comment: How do you run/debug your web app? It's possible that your .js file is deployed somewhere, or stred in the compilation results (`bin` folder of your web app project). But, please, don't run the solution, or you'll overwrite it with the corrupted one. And,from now on, do you a favor and use a CVS to minimize losses. There are free ones that you can install on your same machine. SVN, git or whatever.

Comment: Actually i use git but it was un-commited data.And all the files are in my local computer.

Comment: Sorry for my comment, then. Glad you¡re using CVS. You didn't tell me how you run/debug your app. Do you deploy it to run/test it? There is a chance that your js was deployed on some run. It could also be cached in your browser, so you sould dig your browsers cahce files, but it's a hard task (unless you can grep something inside your js file code). If it was a big or hard to write piece of code, it's worth trying this options.

Comment: It is a web application and i run it in internet explorer. I clear the cache and history after every run of my project. So i think it can not be covered from cache.

Comment: In your web app project properties, there is a Web tab. Are you running it in IIS, local IIS, IIS express? Depending on how you run it there could be a copy of the code. Are you Web APP bin folder empty? Depending on some configuration settings, there is a chance that the file is still somewhere... But it seems more difficult with the new information.

Comment: I use iis express to run the application

Answer (score 0):

Who ever runs in this problem:
I had the same issue and nothing worked for me, chrome cache recover, VS backup was not there looke in AppData folder... nothing!!
Remove the corrupted file, then remove it from windows recycling.
Install a program named Recuva. after this you search for files to recover. If you find your file, recover it.
This was the only thing that worked for me!!!